# Refreshing Page With A Parameter in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a JSP page in my web application and i want to refresh the page with the parameter of option.

```
<select class="form-control combobox"  name="education" >
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose an education</option>
    <option>English</option>
    <option>French</option>
    <option>Dutch</option>
    <option>Spanish</option>
</select>
```

I want to use this parameter for querying my database again. Forexample;

```
 <%

    BookDAO bdao = new BookDAO();
    for (TblBooks book : bdao.getAllBooks()) {%>
    <tr>
        <td><%=book.getTittle()%></td>
        <td><%=boek.getAuthor()%></td>
        <td><%=boek.getCategory()%></td>
        <td><%=boek.getEducation()%></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name ='chk1' /></td>
    </tr>

<% }%>
```

I can get the parameter with request.getParameter("education") but how can i refresh page and query again with this parameter?

Comment: Do you want to refresh the page with the original parameter, or the newly selected parameter?

Comment: @Jason with the new parameter.

Comment: And is this page refresh supposed to happen when the selection changes in the control?

Comment: @Jason yes. Thanx for your answer. I thought to do with javascript but i couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, You can ask a web page to reload itself (the exact same URL) by:

```
location.href = location.href;
```

You can ask a web page to load a different location using the same mechanism:

```
location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; // or whatever destination url you want
```

You can get the value of a `select` control (which needs to have an id attribute):

```
var ctrl = document.getElementById("idOfSelectControl");
var selectedOption = ctrl.options[ctrl.selectedIndex].value;
```

So, if you update your JSP to give the control an id:

```
<select class="form-control combobox" id="education" name="education" >
```

you should be able to reload the page:

```
var educationControl = document.getElementById("education");
var selectedOption = educationControl.options[educationControl.selectedIndex].value;
location.href = "http://mysite.example/mypage?education=" + selectedOption;
```

Answer (score 0):

By the help of Jason i have solved it. I added an onchange event to my select tag

```
onchange="changeThePage()"
```

Then i defined a javascript function.

```
function changeThePage() {

var selectedOption = "book.jsp?education=" + $("#education option:selected").text();

location.href =  selectedOption;

}
```

Then i got the parameter by

```
String education = request.getParameter("education");
```

Then i added `String education` as parameter to my `bdao.getAllBooks(education))` method for to query.

Answer (score 0):

'

```
<script>
function abc(){
    var yourSelect = document.getElementById( "ddlViewBy" );
    var val = yourSelect.options[ yourSelect.selectedIndex ].value;
    //window.location.href=window.location.href;
    alert(val);
    window.location.replace("index.jsp?name="+val);
}
</script>

<select id="ddlViewBy" onchange="abc()">
  <option>select</option>
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
<%
String name=request.getParameter("name");
if(name!=null){
    %>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>author<%=name%></td>
    <td>book name<%=name%></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <%
}
%>
```

Hi,
try this, this will be helpful,
when you select a value it will call abc, function and then you are assigning that value in scriptlet..and also page is refreshing. in scriptlet you can access that value using request.getParameter("name").
now you can write your code inside scriptlet..hope helpful for someone.. :) 
thanks...